# Cons of next.js over create react app + redux + ssr

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, next.js

I have developed an application using React + redux + EJS (with server side rendering) and its running fine in production. I have configured SSR + redux and all the code splitting stuff using webpack config. I have also implemented custom cache middleware to cache the SSR rendered html string ( as needed).

Now, I have been told to refactor the code to suit next.js framework and was wondering the real need for that. What are the main advantages of using next.js if I have already figured out a way to do SSR without next.js framework?

I am not just asking an opinion rather I am trying to understand the real pros/cons of next.js (if any) over CRA.

I have uploaded the boiler plate here if anyone needed a reference: https://github.com/bbest123/reactreduxssr

Comment: I think there is no reasons to rewrite your app with next.js because at least of two reasons:
1) you will be limited with fetching data in components, next.js allows you to add `getInitialProps` only in `Pages`
2) you need to rewrite all `Link` imports in your project. And I don't see any benefits of next.js that will outweigh cons above.

Comment: How will you handle `window` and `document` with your implementation of SSR? Many libraries use `window` or `document` for DOM manipulation (Google Maps, requestAnimationFrame)? If you ever use `react-redux`, how will you implement share the store between server and client? I'd ask yourself what are the advantages of writing the SSR and related functionality yourself rather than using a something community built and maintained like Next,js. Either way this is probably not the best forum for this question it's almost entirely opinion-based. If it's your application, you what YOU want.

Comment: Would you please share your experience with SSR without Next? Did you follow someone recipe or invented your own way? I tried different solutions and they all miss something.

Comment: Check out this project: https://github.com/bbest123/reactreduxssr

Comment: @Vladislav Sorokin checkout the above link

Comment: If you don't know the reasons to refactor it then I think its a waste of time or the person that wants you to refactor it didn't explain to you the benefits. Personally I think nextjs is one of the best node frameworks to use but I wouldn't just go rewriting apps for no known reason.

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

The only con (kind of) I can think of using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is that it's opinionated. It would require you to structure things in a certain way which IMO is still quite extensible.

## Advantages of using Next

- [Simple filesystem routing](https://nextjs.org/#file-system-routing) (plus client side routing with `Link` and prefetching capabilities)
- [Automatic code splitting for your pages](https://nextjs.org/#automatic-code-splitting) (makes keeping bundle sizes in check simple)
- [Out of the box SSR](https://nextjs.org/#server-side-rendering) with a simpler API (than implementing it yourself)
- [Exporting your app as a static site](https://nextjs.org/#static-exporting) (provided you don't need to dynamically server render pages)
- Simpler to extend your babel and webpack config (compared to a non-ejected CRA app)

All these things said, if you've already built your solution without `Next.js` and it works fine for your usecase, IMO there isn't a need to migrate to Next unless you are interested in abstracting some of the configurations and workings of SSR (which `Next.js` would take care of).

## Relevant links

- [Issue on CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2559) discussing comparison with Next (a bit outdated)
- [Alternatives to CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#popular-alternatives) as suggested by CRA docs

Answer (score 4):

One of Nextjs' best features is huge list of 70+ list of implementation examples representing almost every combination of CSS framework, store (flux/redux/mobx/graphQL) framework, node servers, etc.

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples

It is possible to build a react SSR solution without Next.js, but the clean `hooks` for server-side logic (`getInitialProps`, `pages/app.js`, etc ...) are what makes Next.js a top choice here. Next.js shines here by allowing you to write clean, maintainable, and *Performant* SSR web applications.

Lastly, the development team & community is amazing!